# Order by SQL by a string

Tags: sql

In SQL, is it possible to order a query by a string rather than ascending / descending such as the below?

```
Select * From people ORDER BY names (john, steve, bob, bill)
```

Answer (score 16):

In standard SQL, you need a `case` statement

```
Select *
From people
ORDER BY (case when names = 'john' then 1
               when names = 'steve' then 2
               when names = 'bob' then 3
               when names = 'bill' then 4
          else 5
         );
```

Some SQL engines have shortcuts to this, but you don't mention which database you are using.

For instance, in MySQL you can do:

```
order by field(names, 'john', 'steve', 'bob', 'bill');
```

Comment: @user3208629 . . . Yes, this would work if two people were called `'john'`.  Both would appear first in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, use charIndex, i.e.

```
ORDER BY CharIndex('|'+names+'|','|john|steve|bob|bill|')
```

Charindex will return the position of the name found, the earlier in the big list it is found, the lower number returned by charIndex